# Rails: How can I use full stop (.) punctuation mark from en.yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I am not able to display full stop (.) in front-end from en.yml file. But, i am able to display '?' and ',' in front-end from en.yml file.

Below is my current en.yml file.

```
user:
    form:
      user_media: "Please upload a picture to highlight and promote your project. or you can mail it."
      submit: "Submit"
```

Whenever I use the above key for translation it gives output as "or you can mail it"

I want to display the full stop (.) and entire statement.

Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried escaping it with a backslash?

Comment: @engineersmnky yes i tried, but it didn't worked.

Comment: Can you explain how you are translating this because I cannot recreate this using `I18n.t('user.form.user_media') #=> "Please upload a picture to highlight and promote your project. or you can mail it."`